# I am working on a project where I want to convert XML document into html web page using mod xslt. But mod xslt has many limitations

Tags: html, xml, xslt, modulo

Is there any other way to convert XML into HTML web page without using XSLT? Mod XSLT only accepts well-formed XML document. It doesn't process the data if it has ampersand(&) in the XML document.

Comment: Technically a document is only an XML document if it is well-formed. So your input is not XML and trying to use any XML tools like XSLT is not going to work.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is there any other software other than mod xslt which can be used to convert xml into html web pages using xslt stylesheet?

Comment: Well see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info for a long list of XSLT processors. However, the input of XSLT is usually an XML document and any input not following the well-formedness rules outlined in the XML specification does not even get by the XML parser the XSLT processor uses to parse the input.